# seperating parts of the fread output with php for Asterisk AMI

Tags: php, linux, asterisk, centos7, fread

I have a question that has kept me busy for the last days. 
I am working with the Asterisk AMI.

The AMI gives output like this.

```
    Event: RTCPSent
Privilege: reporting,all
Channel: SIP/1001-00000000
ChannelState: 6
ChannelStateDesc: Up
CallerIDNum: <unknown>
CallerIDName: SIP/1001
ConnectedLineNum: <unknown>
ConnectedLineName: SIP/1001
Language: ja
AccountCode: 
Context: phones
Exten: 1000
Priority: 4
Uniqueid: 1535617422.0
Linkedid: 1535617422.0
To: 111.108.30.208:61987
From: 172.31.21.5:20687
SSRC: 0x5847ea3c
PT: 200(SR)

Event: RTCPReceived
Privilege: reporting,all
Channel: SIP/1001-00000000
ChannelState: 6
ChannelStateDesc: Up
CallerIDNum: <unknown>
CallerIDName: SIP/1001
ConnectedLineNum: <unknown>
ConnectedLineName: SIP/1001
Language: ja
AccountCode: 
Context: phones
Exten: 1000
Priority: 4
Uniqueid: 1535617422.0
Linkedid: 1535617422.0
To: 172.31.21.5:20687
From: 111.108.30.208:61987
RTT: 0.0116
SSRC: 0x235022ee
PT: 200(SR)

Event: RTCPSent
Privilege: reporting,all
Channel: SIP/1000-00000001
ChannelState: 6
ChannelStateDesc: Up
CallerIDNum: 1000
CallerIDName: SIP/1001
ConnectedLineNum: <unknown>
ConnectedLineName: SIP/1001
Language: ja
AccountCode: 
Context: phones
Exten: 
Priority: 1
Uniqueid: 1535617431.1
Linkedid: 1535617422.0
To: 111.108.30.208:61044
From: 172.31.21.5:20349
SSRC: 0x0cb019a0
PT: 200(SR)

Event: RTCPReceived
Privilege: reporting,all
Channel: SIP/1000-00000001
ChannelState: 6
ChannelStateDesc: Up
CallerIDNum: 1000
CallerIDName: SIP/1001
ConnectedLineNum: <unknown>
ConnectedLineName: SIP/1001
Language: ja
AccountCode: 
Context: phones
Exten: 
Priority: 1
Uniqueid: 1535617431.1
Linkedid: 1535617422.0
To: 172.31.21.5:20349
From: 111.108.30.208:61044
RTT: 0.0115
SSRC: 0x00294823
PT: 200(SR)
```

I collect the output with the fread() function.

```
fread($fp, 8192);
```

[$fp is the output like here above]

This works but gives the output line by line. 
The correct way to get this would be from a white space line till white space line.

```
    Event: RTCPReceived
Privilege: reporting,all
Channel: SIP/1001-00000000
ChannelState: 6
ChannelStateDesc: Up
CallerIDNum: <unknown>
CallerIDName: SIP/1001
ConnectedLineNum: <unknown>
ConnectedLineName: SIP/1001
Language: ja
AccountCode: 
Context: phones
Exten: 1000
Priority: 4
Uniqueid: 1535617422.0
Linkedid: 1535617422.0
To: 172.31.21.5:20687
From: 111.108.30.208:61987
RTT: 0.0116
SSRC: 0x235022ee
PT: 200(SR)
```

This way I could collect the information that is needed and do the following steps.

Is this possible with the fread function?

I need to read information like who picked up the phone or hangeup.

Your input would be as always highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible.

You should read lines in loop one-by-one until get empty line and merge it in buffer if needed.

Comment: Got an example how that will look like?

Comment: Wish that was possible; the customer doesn't want to use this class.

Comment: So what you want from comunity? You already have alot of samples in multiple phpagi classes, you have samples in php books for beginer. Do you want other people do work instead of you? Read what other people do, link above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! WIll take a look at it.

Comment: To give an update on your answer yesterday, I made it possible by loading the information into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Have made it work by splitting the space to space into an array and checking the error logs. This worked best and gives me the opportunity to read everything out.